# angularjs data structure not work in the view

Tags: angularjs, data-structures, angularjs-ng-repeat, scopes

how repet marcas and how acces to elements in modelos this example...

plnkr.co/edit/aFYv2ynwbwvwWbotU0iJ?p=preview

--- file app.js this structure is incorrect? please helme ---

Comment: I forked your plunkr and corrected some syntax mistakes and updated your JSON model.

Comment: the problematic code should be in your question not just an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some closing `"`s in your example. 
Also, your JSON foramt was not correct. I think you want something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/HPD1FkB5RTA6WwYEHXxz).

Comment: Thanks, the example is perfect... http://plnkr.co/edit/WgcpPZAHRXZVKpHg1l71?p=preview